# If any of date argument is blank, result should be no value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=NETWORKDAYS(Details[Date1]+0,Details[Date2]+0)
```

can you please tell me how do I update the formula if any one of the date argument or both date arguments are blank, I should get the results as blank( not as text 'blank: but just have to result no data)

Here in the formula the
Details is table name
Date1 and Dates2 are column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(NETWORKDAYS(1/(1/Details[Date1]),1/(1/Details[Date2])),"")
```

1. The formula above divides one by the inverse of each number, `1/(1/n)`, in order to coerce zeros into errors, but leave non-zero numbers intact: `1/(1/3)=3` but `1/(1/0)=#DIV/0!`
2. [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) will, in turn, return an error if one of its arguments is an error.
3. [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) is used to return `""` (could be something else) whenever [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it, although it is difficult to deliver an empty cell, but empty string should give the same effect
`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Details[Date1]),ISBLANK(Details[Date2])),"",NETWORKDAYS(Details[Date1]+0,Details[Date2]+0))`

Comment: If the blank is a result of an empty string generated by a formula, for example: `=""` `ISBLANK` returns `FALSE`. Maybe the following is more robust: `(LEN(Details[Date1]) * LEN(Details[Date2]))=0` or just `((Details[Date1]="") * (Details[Date2]=""))=0`

Comment: Can you please send me the full formula with network days function?

Comment: =IF(OR(ISBLANK(Details[Date1]),ISBLANK(Details[Date2])),"",NETWORKDAYS(Details[Date1]+0,Details[Date2]+0)) This formula is printing all the values in the column as empty string

Comment: Here is the full formula: `=IF(((Details[Date1]="") + (Details[Date2]=""))>0, "", NETWORKDAYS(Details[Date1]+0,Details[Date2]+0))` I corrected the formula in my previous comment

Comment: @Maddy if you expect accuracy in any of the answers, then next time please provide a sample data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) otherwise people will provide a formula without being able to test it. People trying to help responding need data to test it, and the OP (you) should facilitate this process. It reduces unnecessary back and forward interactions.

Comment: Sure David, will do it from next. Thank you for your response. I got the answer for my question.